# Need to create a formula with the operand in a different cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

For eg .

Existing formula which works
**Query(A4:K,"Select A Where I = > 0.3")**

should be replaced by
**Query(A4:K,"Select A Where I = "&N1&"")**

with cell N1 containing value '>0.3'

Appreciate any help

Comment: No, `Query(A4:K,"Select A Where I = > 30%")` does not work.

Comment: How abt this Query(A4:K,"Select A Where I = >  0.3")

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: Thanks for the link, but not sure what to do

Answer (score 1):

`= >` is not a valid operator the following operators are valid `<=, <, >, >=, =, !=, <>`

Your first code should look like this

```
Query(A4:K,"Select A Where I >= 0.3")
```

Your second code would look like this (Assuming N1 contains `>0.3`)

```
Query(A4:K,"Select A Where I "&N1)
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Comment: Tried it that doesnt seem to work, heres the link to the file, hoping you can identify the issue. Code is in the first sheet on Line M4 to Q4  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10_C_2rTWD-3pVTpbEvKXFy834TI5zH6806bT6jsC3m0/edit?pli=1#gid=1978341172

Comment: It is working fine, the output is showing #N/A because there is nothing to return you have all 0%

Comment: it showing #value,  unable to parse query string. there are several row which have value greater than 33% in the column . try someother value , error still remains

Comment: see cell Q4, have made the change there

Comment: @VikramChander I just looked at your sheet, you need to read the first sentence of my answer, `= >` is not a valid operator the following operators are valid `<=, <, >, >=, =, !=, <>`